# CSS / HTML double font color into a SELECT OPTION

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I have a little problem with customize CSS/HTML of select option

This is my code :

```
<select id="Month" class="form-styling-date splash_small required" title=" " style="" name="Month" tabindex="12">
<option value="1">Janvier</option>
<option value="2">Février</option>
....
<option value="11">Novembre</option>
<option value="12">Décembre</option>
<option value="9999" selected="selected">Mois</option>
</select>
```

This is my CSS code :

```
.form-styling-date {
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
```

you can see the problem in : https://gayurban.com/sync/indexv2.php and select SIGN UP option into BIRTHDAY

I customise CSS to write the selected option in WHITE when is selected, so when you select the arrow to see all the options, the background AND font color set to white. So i can't see the list of options.

How can change this font color to BLACK and when is selected turn to WHITE because when i set the font color to BLACK i see the list so font color black into the form is not really a visible choice.

Thank for your help

Comment: give style in your selectbox

Comment: @LiTHiUM2525, Better to add generic styles to tag selector, if you want your CSS to remain same through your whole site. And add specific styles based on class selector, where you want to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give

```
.form-styling-date option{color: black;}
```

in `main.css` file at line 243.

Comment: Will this class selector won't limit the scope? I mean, OP would require to add this class to the select(s), where he wants to add this style, rather it is of type date or not.

Comment: Yes i add it to all scope needed TY

Answer (score 4):

`color` property on `select` will set color of option(s) text (including selected), while adding / over-riding color to `select option` will set color of options excluding selected option, which will be set based on the value specified for `select`.

**CSS:**

```
select {
  color: white; /* color of selected option */
 }

select option {
  color: black; /* color of other options */
}
```

Also, better to add generic styles to tag selector, if you want your component CSS to remain same through your site. And add specific styles based on class / id selector(s), where you want to change them.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/parkashkumar37/ggv3j4ve/)

Answer (score 1):

Keep your select as white, but then override your select option as black in your case:

```
.form-styling-date option{
   color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
color: white;}


::selection {
color: white;}
```

Update default style to black :)

Answer (score 0):

this is problem with your **CSS**.
Add this **CSS** in your page. because this page contain **three select** all this color is white.

```
select option{
    color:#000;
}
```